# отправка письма на NodeJs

Tags: node.js

доброго

В PHP есть чудесная команда mail(), которая позволяет отправить простенькое письмо без захода в свой ящик, и прочего. Просто пишем 3 параметра и отправляем. В NodeJS не могу найти похожую команду. Везде только дополнительные расширения в которых надо авторизоваться по ключу или войти в свой email для отправки

Вопрос: как отправить письмо в NodeJS без авторизации в своем email и без сторонних сервисов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### В общем, никак.

**Эта "чудесная команда `mail()`" на самом деле тоже требует настройки,** но в неожиданных местах.

- На *nix она использует системный `sendmail`, который обычно настраивается администратором перед вводом сервера в эксплуатацию.
- На Windows она шлёт письмо через SMTP-сервер, реквизиты которого нужно указать в конфигурации PHP.

Если ничего из вышеперечисленного не настроено, то `mail()` ничего послать не сможет. Так что **аутентифицироваться придётся в любом случае** (разве что вы найдёте какой-нибудь публичный SMTP-сервер, письма от которого попадают в спам с вероятностью около 100%).

Так что вам придётся использовать одно из расширений, "в которых надо авторизоваться по ключу или войти в свой email для отправки". Потому что в конечном счёте этим всё и заканчивается. Волшебства не бывает. `mail` лишь абстрагируется от конкретных служб отправки, позволяя не париться о процедуре аутентификации в коде отправки письма.

Вам ничто не мешает сделать отдельный модуль отправки почты с заданным конфигурационным файлом и одной функцией `mail`, торчащей наружу.

---

Это на практике. **Теоретически**, возможность есть.

Глобальная система e-mail же как-то работает, серверы обмениваются письмами между собой. Это не аутентификация через аутентификацию.

Для этого вам нужно достать домен из адреса получателя и запросить у DNS его MX-запись. Так вы узнаете, какой почтовый сервер обеспечивает доставку сообщений по указанному адресу. После чего отослать письмо ему напрямую. Это реализуется пакетами [вроде `directmailer`](https://github.com/andris9/directmail).

Почему на практике это обычно нежизнеспособно? Спам. Точнее, контрмеры против спама. С очень высокой вероятностью у любых крупных провайдеров письма, отправленные таким образом, будут уходить в спам, как "не внушающие доверия". С этим можно справиться, но сложно.

Поэтому многие и пользуются крупными почтовыми службами, которые проблемы с доверием уже решили, а с отправкой спама через свои службы борются достаточно активно, чтобы другие службы им доверяли.

Comment: уважаемый @D-side, а существуют уже реализованные модули для отправки почты под node.js? ? так сказать с `заданным конфигурационным файлом и одной функцией mail, торчащей наружу`

Comment: @stas0k всё равно любой модуль общего назначения нужно хотя бы однажды сконфигурировать для конкретного приложения, и очень даже хорошо, что модули не навязывают какой-то конкретный способ. Сам не пишу на Node.js, просто наугад влез в гугл по запросу `nodejs mail package` и нашёл [NodeMailer](https://nodemailer.com/): ему достаточно URL с реквизитами. И если я правильно понимаю систему модулей NodeJS, можно сделать маленький модуль, в котором при старте создать объект по реквизитами и экспортировать его функцию `sendMail` наружу. Всё. Модуль, экспортирующий одну функцию для отправки письма.

Comment: благодарю, по ошибке подумал что вы имеете большой опыт на nodejs.

Comment: дык.. скачать модуль не беда, проблема в том, что первые 100 строк в гугле, это как раз решения со входом в почту, и отправки из под нее, что не катит ((

Comment: @serg вы невнимательно прочитали ответ?

Comment: прочитал внимательно. Локально аутенфицироваться зачем? все разрешено, но вопрос как, остается открытым. Локально же пробовал некоторые решения, которые спокойно слали мэйлы. к сожалению решения сейчас найти не могу. соответственно вопрос, как?

Comment: @serg ну, если вы так хотите приключений, я ещё дополнил ответ :)